# Unable to click submit button using selenium

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to find and click a button using Selenium. I've been searching for a solution for some time now but everything I try seems to fail.

The HTML code looks as follows:

```
<button class="button viewad-contact-submit" type="submit">
            <span>Nachricht senden</span>
            </button>
```

Previously I have tried:

```
submit_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')
submit_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(@id, 'viewad-contact-submit')
submit_button = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id = "button viewad-contact-submit"]')
```

I no longer get the "Unable to locate element" error when I use the first solution in the above list, but still no button is being clicked. I have also tried including some "time.sleep(5)" to make sure the website is not just slow when loading.

The click action comes later a couple lines down:

```
submit_button.click()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am new to programming and it's my first time using Selenium. Also, first post on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Second and third solution from your list are not working because xpath is not correct. You should replace @id by @class.

And for clicking particular element you can also try submit() function when button type is ‘submit’

So try:

```
submit_button.submit()
```

Comment: I believe it was the "submit_button.submit()" that did the trick! Thank you!