# Click a custom button using Selenium with Python3

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver, button, firefox, click

I am trying to use Selenium to click the "button" with the text "Expand all" (see attached screenshot). I am using Selenium `v4.15.2`. Each line below represents some test which either returns an empty [], OR an error that it can't find the element, OR the element does not have a click/submit attribute:

```
#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//*[contains(text(), 'awsui-button-region')]")

#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//div[@class='_alignRight_dku4v_1259']")

#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", '//button[@class="awsui-button awsui-button-variant-normal awsui-hover-child-icons"]').click()

#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", '//button[@class="awsui-button awsui-button-variant-normal awsui-hover-child-icons"]')

#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//button[text()='comm-expand-all']")
```

The "div class" in the screenshot is nested about 5 levels deep in other "div class"(es).

I also tried to implement something similar this with no luck: [Unable to click submit button using selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57921102/unable-to-click-submit-button-using-selenium)

```
#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//button[contains (@class, 'awsui-button awsui-button-variant-normal awsui-hover-child-icons')]")

#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//button[(@class = 'awsui-button awsui-button-variant-normal awsui-hover-child-icons')]")
```

I also tried using the xpath (and full xpath) copied from Developer mode:

```
#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/section/div/awsui-app-layout/div/main/div/div[2]/div[2]/span/div/div/section/div/section/awsui-tabs/div/div/div[4]/span/section/div/div/div/div/awsui-button/button")

#chks = driver.find_elements("xpath", '//*[@id="awsui-tabs-0-correspondences-panel"]/span/section/div/div/div/div/awsui-button/button')
```

I need to click the "button" so it expands all the sections of the page. If clicked, the text changes to "Collapse all". I am attempting to download the page (using `driver.page_source`), but if I don't expand all the sections, the exact text (addresses) I am searching for are that included in the downloaded page. Thanks.
[Expand All button][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYFbx.jpg

Comment: Can you post html page of control?

Comment: Thanks Ketan. I added a screenshot of the section including the button. Let me know if additional details is required. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out:

1. Get the get the relative XPath of the button using the following steps (the absolute XPath didn't work)
2. Open the page in Chrome,
3. Right-click on the button and select "Inspect" from the menu
4. This opens the "Elements" tab of "Developer Tools" with the "<span ..." line of the button in focus
5. Right-click on the line and select "Copy" > "Copy XPath" from the menu
6. To get the XPath of the button, delete the trailing "/span" from the copied XPath:  //*[@id="awsui-tabs-0-correspondences-panel"]/span/section/div/div/div/div/awsui-button/button/span
7. Alternative to the previous step, right-click on the "<button class=..." line right above the highlighted "<span ..." line and select "Copy" > "XPath" from the menu. This is the relative XPath of the button and it is what you need:  //*[@id="awsui-tabs-0-correspondences-panel"]/span/section/div/div/div/div/awsui-button/button
8. You must maximize the browser window (driver.maximize_window())
9. Use the relative XPath in your code to get the button:  theButton = driver.find_elements("xpath", "//*[@id='awsui-tabs-0-correspondences-panel']/span/section/div/div/div/div/awsui-button/button")
10. Use a loop to click the button (it didn't work for me without the loop)

```
for i in theButton:
   i.click()
```